# How to add a default step within GCP Workflows after switch case within a try block?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow

I would like to include a default step to go to after a switch statement is completed within a try/except statement.
For instance, within this example here: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/conditions#json I would like to add the "next": "STEP_NAME_D" after a switch statement. Within a try/catch block I can't seem to add the "next" step after the switch statement and was wondering if there was some sort of work around that was possible.

Apparently doing something like this is ok:

```
{
   switch: arr,
   next: 'Default',
}
```

But this isn't ok?

```
try: {
  switch: arr,
  next: 'Default',
}
```

Wasn't quite sure why and some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> include a default step to go to after a switch statement is completed within a try/except statement.

If your intention is to have a default step that is always executed after the `switch` statement, regardless of which condition in the `switch` is satisfied, you will need to include the "`next`" action in each `switch` condition itself, as the execution will directly jump to the mentioned step when a condition is true.

See also "[Example of try/except structure](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/catching-errors)".

Yo would modify the workflow like this:

```yaml
- try_this: 
    try:
      steps:
      - switch_step:
          switch:
            - condition: ${some_condition}
              return: Condition_Met_Value
            - condition: ${other_condition}
              return: Other_Condition_Met_Value
      - default_step:
          assign:
            - default: ${switch_step}
    catch:
      - error_handler:
          assign:
            - error: ${last.error}
```

Meaning: instead of using `next` in the switch, we use `return`. The result of the `switch` statement is assigned to `default` in the `default_step` which is always executed after the `switch` statement.

That approach ensures that regardless of which condition is met in the `switch`, the `default_step` will always execute immediately after the `switch` statement. If an error occurs during these steps, the `catch` block will be executed.